# How can I deserialize an non-fixed array of jsons using Circe's manual decoder?

Tags: scala, circe, sttp

I have a JSON that looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "email": "hello@world.com",
      "name": "Mr foo",
      "roles": [
        "Chief Bar Officer"
      ],
      "avatar_url": null,
      "phone_number": null
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "email": "bye@world.com",
      "name": "Mr baz",
      "roles": [
        "Chief Baz Officer"
      ],
      "avatar_url": null,
      "phone_number": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I am mainly interested in parsing/deserializing the data list, and I would like to do that manually (I prefer the manual way for some mysterious reason).

In case this is relevant, I am using sttp's circe library `sttp.client.circe._` with the intention of parsing  incoming data from get requests directly into Json using `asJson`.

A get sttp request looks something like:

```
val r1 = basicRequest
    .get(uri"https://woooo.woo.wo/v1/users")
    .header("accept", "application/json")
    .header("Authorization", "topsecret"
    .response(asJson[SomeClass])
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
// Define the case class
case class User(
    id: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    roles: List[String],
    avatar_url: Option[String],
    phone_number: Option[String]
)

// Define the manual deserializer

case object User {

  implicit val userDecoder: Decoder[User] = (hCursor: HCursor) => {
    val data = hCursor.downField("data").downArray
    for {
      id <- data.get[String]("id")
      email <- data.get[String]("email")
      name <- data.get[String]("name")
      roles <- data.get[List[String]]("roles")
      avatarUrl <- data.get[Option[String]]("avatarUrl")
      phoneNumber <- data.get[Option[String]]("phoneNumber")
    } yield User(id, email, name, roles, avatarUrl, phoneNumber)
  }
}
```

The problem with my approach (I think) is that `.downArray` makes me only serialize the first User in the array of Users.

My objective is to be able to have some sequence of users (something like `List[User]` maybe), but at the moment I only end up deserializing one user in the array.

It is worth mentioning that the "data" array, does not contain a fixed-number of users, and every api call could result in a different number of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) and the [circe Gitter community](https://gitter.im/circe/circe) for helping me figure this one out.

I'm quoting Travis here:

> it would be better to build up the instance you need to parse the
> top-level JSON object compositionally… i.e. have a Decoder[User] that
> only decodes a single user JSON object, and then use
> Decoder[List[User]].at("data") or something similar to decode the
> top-level JSON object containing the data field with the JSON array.

I have ended up with an implementation that looks something like:

```
case class Users(users: List[User])

case object User {

  implicit val usrDecoder: Decoder[User] = (hCursor: HCursor) => {

    for {
      id <- hCursor.get[String]("id")
      email <- hCursor.get[String]("email")
      name <- hCursor.get[String]("name")
      roles <- hCursor.get[List[String]]("roles")
      avatarUrl <- hCursor.get[Option[String]]("avatarUrl")
      phoneNumber <- hCursor.get[Option[String]]("phoneNumber")
    } yield User(id, email, name, roles, avatarUrl, phoneNumber)
  }

  implicit val decodeUsers: Decoder[Users] =
    Decoder[List[User]].at("data").map(Users)

}
```

The idea is to compose the Decoder of a User, and the Decoder for a collection of Users separately. And then by mapping `Users` to the Decoder, we wrap the results of the Decoder into the Users case class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decode `List[User]` you'd need to create decoder for exact type `List[User]`. It might look like:

```
implicit val userDecoder: Decoder[List[User]] = (hCursor: HCursor) => {
    Either.fromOption(
      hCursor.downField("data").values,
      DecodingFailure("Can't decode data", Nil)
    ).flatMap { values =>
      values.toList.map(_.hcursor).traverse {
        userCursor =>
          for {
            id <- userCursor.get[String]("id")
            email <- userCursor.get[String]("email")
            name <- userCursor.get[String]("name")
            roles <- userCursor.get[List[String]]("roles")
            avatarUrl <- userCursor.get[Option[String]]("avatarUrl")
            phoneNumber <- userCursor.get[Option[String]]("phoneNumber")
          } yield User(id, email, name, roles, avatarUrl, phoneNumber)
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
json.as[List[User]]
```

This might be not the best idea, since circe can already decode json arrays into list, so it might be better idea, to just create decoder for user (decoding object):

```
implicit val userDecoder: Decoder[User] = (hCursor: HCursor) =>
  for {
    id <- hCursor.get[String]("id")
    email <- hCursor.get[String]("email")
    name <- hCursor.get[String]("name")
    roles <- hCursor.get[List[String]]("roles")
    avatarUrl <- hCursor.get[Option[String]]("avatarUrl")
    phoneNumber <- hCursor.get[Option[String]]("phoneNumber")
} yield User(id, email, name, roles, avatarUrl, phoneNumber)
```

In this case you'd have manually go down `data` field:

```
json.hcursor.downField("data").as[List[User]]
```

Yet another possibility is to just create case class for `data` wrapper:

```
  case class Data[D](data: D)

  object Data {
    implicit def dataDecoder[D: Decoder]: Decoder[Data[D]] =
      (hCursor: HCursor) => hCursor.get[D]("data").map(Data(_))
  }
```

Then you can do something like:

```
json.as[Data[List[User]]]
```